# PHP: fsockopen() expect parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, html, sockets

i have a problem with the line 10 (**$f = fsockopen($server, 43, $ae_whois_errno, $ae_whois_errstr, AE_WHOIS_TIMEOUT);**). when i write an URL in the input field a warning occurs: "**Warning: fsockopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Client-Server\whoisclient.php on line 10**". Here's the code.

```
 <?php 
    include("preliminari.php");
    function ae_whois($query, $server)
    {

        define('AE_WHOIS_TIMEOUT', 15); // connection timeout
        global $ae_whois_errno, $ae_whois_errstr;

        // connecting 
        $f = fsockopen($server, 43, $ae_whois_errno, $ae_whois_errstr, AE_WHOIS_TIMEOUT);
        if (!$f) 
            return false; // connection failed 

        // sending query    
        fwrite($f, $query."\r\n");

        // receving response 
        $response = '';
        while (!feof($f))
            $response .= fgets($f, 1024);

        // closing connection 
        fclose($f);

        return $response;
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Whois client con i socket del PHP</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .body {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    .titolo {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $indirizzo  = $_GET['dominio'];
    $dom = explode(".",$indirizzo);
    $campi = count($dom)-1;
    $query = "select servername from whois where dominio = '".$dom[$campi]."'";
    $server = mysql_query($query);
    if (isset ($indirizzo)) {
        $reply = ae_whois ($indirizzo, $server);
        $reply = nl2br ($reply);
        echo "<p>$reply</p>";
    }
    ?>
    <h2 align="center" class="titolo">Whois di un dominio</h2>
    <form name="ricerca" method="get" action="whoisclient.php">
    <p align="center" class="body">Nome del dominio</p>
    <p align="center" class="body">
      <input name="dominio" type="text">
    </p>
    <p align="center" class="body"><input name="go" type="submit" value="WHOIS"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: $server must be a string and it seems not to be a string. How is $server initialized?

Comment: $server is the result of a query: $query="select servername from whois where dominio=' ".$dom[$campi]." ' ";   $server=mysql_query($query);

Comment: Have you then got the value of the correct column? $server must be something like www.example.com

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: $server is something like "whois.nic.ac" or "whois.aeda.net.ae"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have server as the query, but you have not specified a result.

You would then need mysql_fetch_assoc to get a value a out.

```
 $s =mysql_query($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($s)) {
     $server = $row['servername'];
 }
```

You should also seriously consider using mysqli or pdo instead. [php mysql query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I've implemented that solution but now when i write something like "www.arduino.cc" the resulting output is "No match for "WWW.ARDUINO.CC"

Comment: Same thing with www.youtube.com

Comment: you are trying to select rows of data matching domain names. If those domains are not in your table, nothing will be returned.

Comment: Yes, because i've added an echo of the corresponding servername an it appears at the top of the page

Comment: @danieletedesco That's expected. `www.arduino.cc` isn't a registered domain, so it won't be in WHOIS; `arduino.cc` is, though. Ditto for Youtube.